# How to fix CSS transform issue on Mac/iOS devices?

Tags: html, css, iphone, testing, browser

My website is only HTML, CSS, and JS. However, when I open it on iPhone devices it shows the simple HTML screen cut in half like this:

[image: website displaying only half on iPhone]

On all other devices, it works perfect:

[image: website showing properly on other devices]

This is a code snippet to test:

```css
#popupOnStart{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: 0.8s opacity ease-in-out;
}
#popupOnStart .button .textGlowed{
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff;
    /* animation: glowing 1s infinite; */
}
#popupOnStart .portfolioIntro{
    position: fixed;
    /* padding: 100px 0 20px 0; */
    top: 100px;
    text-align: start;
    /* right: 125px; */
}
#popupOnStart.hidePopup{
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
#popupOnStart .button{
    background-color: #0000;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 35px;
    transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 1, -72deg);
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: visible;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    user-select: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 560px){
    #popupOnStart .button:hover{
        transform: rotate3d(2, 2, 2, -55deg);
    }
    #popupOnStart .buttonEffect:hover{
        width: 105%;
        height: 105%;
        top: -2.5%;
        left: -2.5%;
    }
    #popupOnStart .buttonEffect:hover:not(.edge){
        filter: hue-rotate(70deg) !important;
    }
    .buttonEffect {
        filter: brightness(1.5) hue-rotate(30deg);
        animation: light-filter 1s infinite;
    }
    #popupOnStart .button .textGlowed{
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff;
        animation: glowing 1s infinite;
    }
}
/* #popupOnStart .button:active{
    transform: scale(3)
} */
/* #popupOnStart .button.clickedButton{
    overflow: hidden;
} */
#popupOnStart .button .textGlowed{
    content: 'START';
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    font-size: 22px;
    z-index: 4;
}
#popupOnStart .buttonEffect{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    filter: blur(2px);
    border-radius: 25px;
}
#popupOnStart .front{
    background-color: #000000ad;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px blue, 0 0 50px blue;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
}
#popupOnStart .button.clickedButton .front, #popupOnStart .button.clickedButton .textGlowed{
    transform: translate3d(-27px, 20px, 0) scale(0.95);
}
#popupOnStart .shadow{
    background-color: #4177c28d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px blue;
    transform: translate3d(-40px, 30px, 0);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
#popupOnStart .edge{
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px blue;
    transform: translate3d(-40px, 30px, 0);
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px blue, 0 0 50px blue;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.buttonEffect {
    filter: brightness(1.5) hue-rotate(30deg);
    /* animation: light-filter 1s infinite; */
}

@keyframes light-filter {
    0% {
        filter: brightness(1.5) hue-rotate(30deg);
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px blue, 0 0 20px blue, 0 0 300px blue;
    }
    50% {
        filter: brightness(1) hue-rotate(0deg);
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px blue, 0 0 20px blue, 0 0 300px blue;
    }
    100% {
        filter: brightness(1.5) hue-rotate(30deg);
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px blue, 0 0 20px blue, 0 0 300px blue;
    }
}
#popupOnStart .button .textGlowed{
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff;
    /* animation: glowing 1s infinite; */
}
@keyframes glowing {
    0% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff;
    }
    50% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff;
    }
    100% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff;
    }
}
.lightEffect{
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    /* z-index: 1; */
    /* background-color: var(--backgroundColor); */
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #e60073, 0 0 40px #e60073, 0 0 50px #e60073, 0 0 60px #e60073, 0 0 70px #e60073; */
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 200px #fff, 0 0 300px #e60073, 0 0 400px #e60073, 0 0 500px #e60073, 0 0 600px #e60073, 0 0 700px #e60073;
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div id="popupOnStart">
        <div class="portfolioIntro">
            <strong>
            </strong>
        </div>
        <button class="button">
            <div class="buttonEffect edge"></div>
            <div class="buttonEffect shadow"></div>
            <div class="buttonEffect front"></div>
            <div class="textGlowed">START</div>
          </button>
          <audio id="myAudio" src="./audio/space-age-10714.mp3"></audio>
          <div class="developedBy animate__animated animate__slideInUp">
          </div>
    </div>
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this issue?

I tried removing all the JavaScript, but it still doesn't get fixed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.

Comment: Have you checked on caniuse.com? For instance it says 'In Safari filter won't apply to child elements while they are animating'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying now testing with my iphone and I managed to get the whole image by removing this line of code in #popupOnStart:

```
background: #000;
```

The problem may arise because Apple devices have slightly different rendering requirements than other devices. Some CSS transformations may not display correctly on such devices.

Comment: yes, thank you.
I have been noticing this since a while ago. apple devices don't function proberly in many css logic.